# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest() and Redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I want to send a XMLRequest to server and then redirect user to front page so far 
I have:

```
var posts = new XMLHttpRequest();
var api="XXXXXXXXXX";
posts.open("GET", api+user+"/"+password+"/"+id+"/"+latitude, true);
posts.send();

window.location = "index.html"
```

If I only run the code without the redirect at the end it works great but if I have a the redirect the API GET request fails. Can someone explain to me what I'm missing?

Comment: It is asynchronous. The browser is redirected before the result it back.

Comment: If you're doing the XHR in order to make something happen at the server, you really should do a POST and not a GET to avoid a very simple CSRF vulnerability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The requests are **asynchronous** that means window.location will not wait for the request to complete before executing.
That results in navigating away from the current page and the browser canceling the request.

To fix this you have to wait for the request to complete before navigating away. You can do this by listening to the state changes of the request.

```js
var posts = new XMLHttpRequest();
posts.onreadystatechange = function() { // listen for state changes
  if (posts.readyState == 4 && posts.status == 200) { // when completed we can move away
    window.location = "index.html";
  }
}
posts.open("GET", api+user+"/"+password+"/"+id+"/"+latitude, true);
posts.send();
```

Comment: Thanks. I also should be able to change: posts.open("GET", api+user+"/"+password+"/"+id+"/"+latitude,  **false**);

Comment: You can but it's not indicated. That means the event loop will not run any code until the request completes, making your page non-responsive. :)

Comment: Oh I see the difference. Thanks

Comment: @SeanM if the answer satisfies your needs please mark it as correct so other people will see it too. :)

Comment: Documentation says this is deprecated. Seems to work fine for now, but for future-proofing is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: @rococo which part of it are you seeing as deprecated? If you don't want to use the XMLHttpRequest you can use the fetch api which has a nice Promise based interface that's a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but I read "in fact, many browsers have deprecated synchronous XHR support on the main thread entirely" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) and "Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). Will check out `fetch` and `await`, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @rococo the synchronous part is indeed deprecated, but the solution I posted doesn't use that anyway.

Comment: Ohh yes you're right. I think I may have gotten mixed up while reading through several different questions and thought this answer was one that used the `async` flag of `open` to force the request to be synchronous. This is a very nice approach, my bad!

Comment: just as a note, using the async flag does not make the request synchronous, it does exactly what I did in my answer here, it's just hidden from you and makes the code look like it's synchronous. In fact it moves the code after the `await` into the `then` part of the fetch promise.